# Do I need to vent a crawlspace?

Tags: foundation, crawlspace, venting, dehumidifier

We just completed a 20x20 great room addition on the side of our house with a 4 foot crawl space and poured concrete floor. There is a 4’ by 4’ cut through to access this crawl space from the existing full sized basement. We live in New England. The new addition has baseboard heat and the floor is insulated with insulation bats. The new addition includes 3 foundation vents (metal with screens, we can slide them open or closed) for the crawl space. The rest of the existing basement has no venting to the outside (just a door with stairs to a bulkhead).

The contractor said these are required and wants them left open. However, in the winter - even if we slide the vent closed, cold air is making the floors cold and it just lets cold air into the normal existing basement which will be half finished.

Do we need these vents or can I just plug them with some sort of ridid foam insulation?  All this cold air seams like a big waste of energy. In the summer we keep a dehumidifier running - is this enough to keep the crawl space conditioned as well?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Is there a reason why you wouldn't close off and insulate that 4' x 4' cut-through from your full-sized basement to the new crawl space?

Comment: I am open to closing this off if recommended.  My thought was that if we seal the crawlspace vents, then warmer air from the basement could pass into this crawlspace to help keep it warmer (reducing risk of heating pipes freezing, keeping the living space above it warmer)

Comment: Wait: your extension is electric, not forced water, right? If so, then what's going to freeze in the crawlspace?

Comment: No - it is baseboard heat (non-electric).  the feed for those baseboard units is under the floor.

Comment: So, letting the crawlspace freeze wouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: well - there is the possibility that he pipes that run to the baseboard heat (which are insulated but in the floor joist area) could freeze up.  Additionally - if the crawlspace freezes, the addition above remains very cold (cold floors, etc.)

Comment: Sorry: didn't read carefully. Your extension has forced water baseboard heat, and the pipes need to be kept warm. If they're underneath the floor insulation, then that's a big problem, and needs to be fixed; once fixed, you can let the crawlspace freeze. If they are above the insulation, then you're already good. (Right?)